# f77 undefined reference to getgid_

Tags: makefile, fortran

I was told to post compiling questions on stackoverflow so this is the same question I've [posted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688994/f77-undefined-reference-to-getgid) to Ubuntu Ask!:

I'm trying to compile a program that came with a Makefile. The makefile uses f77 and it seems that the programs call several f95 intrinsics. When I try to compile I get:

```
plotkit.a(userid.o): In function userid_':
fort77-5163-1.c:(.text+0x13e): undefined reference togetgid_' fort77-5163-1.c:(.text+0x234): undefined reference to `getuid_' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also get the same error with fdate on another program in this distribution. I've tried to change the makefile to use different compilers such as gfortran) and they all cause MORE errors.

My question is how do I get getgid, getuid, and fdate to work with a f77 program? I'm additionally confused because there are getgid and getuid man pages but no installation on ubuntu?

I have a 64 bit 14.04 LTS installation.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: What kind of compiler is the `f77`? What package does it come from? Those intrinsics are non-standard, not even f90, but completely non-standard. Not every compiler knows them.

Answer (score 2):

By default, gfortran (and other Fortran compilers) mangle procedure names by adding an underscore.  When you reference `getgid` in source, the compiler changes that to `getgid_`.  If the function `getgid` isn't defined in Fortran source, e.g. in C, then this will cause link errors such as the one you are encountering.

The functions `getgid`, `getuid`, etc are not Fortran functions, they are standard C library functions.  If the code you are using is from somewhere else, look and see if the provided Makefiles have options listed to disable default underscoring by Fortran.   For gfortran, this option is `-fno-underscoring`.  Append this to the compiler flags used for the Fortran compiler in the makefile.  For other Fortran compilers, consult their documentation for similar options.

If you aren't restricted to F77 and can make use of modern Fortran features, the other option is to fix this by providing interoperable interfaces for C library functions.  e.g.

```
interface
  function getgid() bind(C,name='getgid')
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    integer(c_int32_t) :: getgid
  end function getgid
end interface
```

This will define an explicit interface for the C library function `getgid` so that you can call it from a modern Fortran implementation.  You would define interfaces like this for each of the C library functions you need to call.

* As an aside, while the above interface works and is portable from a modern Fortran perspective, it isn't 100% portable from a C library perspective.  The GNU implementation of `getgid` returns the type `gid_t` which though a long chain of typedefs is finally related to a true type in the files `/usr/include/bits/types.h` and  `/usr/include/bits/typesizes.h` as an unsigned 32 bit integer.  Fortran doesn't have unsigned types so while the storage sizes will match, if these functions ever return values above around 2 billion, they will be misinterpreted in Fortran as negative values.  Also, since the storage type of `gid_t` is defined in the "bits" C header tree, they are potentially non-portable (not sure if the storage size is specified in POSIX or some other standard or implementation dependent).